# How to apply a transformation to a grid?

Tags: plotting, coordinate-transformation

I would like to apply a coordinate transformation, visualised as an action on a two-dimensional grid like

[image: grid]

The particular example above is
$$x^\mu \mapsto \frac{x^\mu - b^\mu x^2}{1-b\cdot x+ b^2 x^2}.$$

Comment: What is the representation of your grid?  Lines?  Points?  Functions?

Comment: Use ParametricPlot for that purpose

Comment: Related (with downloadable notebook): http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConformalMapping.html

Answer (score 6):

If you want a point-to-point transformation:

```
f[x_: List, b_: List] := (x - b (x.x))/(1 + (b.x) + (b.b) (x.x));

myinput = DeleteDuplicates@
   Flatten[Union[Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 10, 1}, {j, 0, 10, .01}], 
     Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 10, .011}, {j, 0, 10, 1}]], 1];

ListPlot[myinput]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[f[#, {.5, .1}] & /@ myinput]
```

[image]